# trigger on email sent to third party email id from salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, email, apex-email-service

Wanted to track emails sent from salesforce to any third party email ids and not the contacts or any internal user.

Answer (score 0):

Two Options are Available

1. Email Logs [Setup -> Logs -> Email logs]
2. Compliance BCC Email  [Setup -> Email administration -> Compliance BCC Email]